# Commence "on" vs. "from"

Tags: sentence-construction

> The examination will commence _____  Monday.

a) **on**
b) **from**

which of the above will be used? 
Also explain, how commence is used.

In my opinion, it should be **"from"**.

Answer (score 2):

> The examination will commence **on** Monday.

says Monday is the starting date. It is unknown if it will last for only one day or additional days.

> The examination will commence **from** Monday.

implies it will start on Monday but continue for one or more days. There is an implied "to":

> The examination will commence **from** Monday and continue **to** Wednesday.